# Can I find out if a server supports a specific Content-Encoding of http requests?

Tags: http, rest, web-applications, webserver, content-encoding

Could someone please tell me if it is possible to find out if a server supports a particular Content-Encoding or not?

I am making REST API calls to multiple servers and it seems some don't support "gzip" Content-Encoding of the requests. Can I negotiate these details at runtime, find out if the server can handle the de-compression and compress the request body, only if it can?

Am I missing something basic?

Regards,
Roshan